# Replacing Sawzip in Javascript | zipping files using javascript in windows

Tags: javascript, zip

I'm not good with web based technologies so apologies if the question is dumb.

Currently in our system, there is a legacy application coded in windows script file(wsf). This wsf refers another `javascript` file to zip files. The JavaScript uses another app called SawZip to zip files. Here is the code.

Note, there is no web calls or anything as such. This code only used to create zip files and place it in windows path

```
var arrfile = //list of files
var arch = new ActiveXObject("SAWZIP.Archive")
var tmpzip = path+"\\_tmp.zip"
arch.Create(tmpzip)
for (var i = 0; i < arrfile.length; i++) {
    arch.Files.AddFileByName(arrfile[i], 5, false, true);
}
arch.Close();
```

Our company wants to remove the sawzip dependency since the source and authenticity of sawzip application is unknown.

After some research, everyone seem to suggest JSZip to zip file, but looks like it is used to download files in browser.

My question is, is it even possible ? If yes, please provide some pointers. I'm not looking for exact answers, pointers should be enough

Comment: How are you running your JS scripts ?

Comment: @Seblor We will not call the Javascript directly. `.Wsf` file be called `c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe d:\test\generate.wsf` inside the `.wsf` file, javascript file will be referred.